# par files why do we use it in java development

Tags: java, ant, par

We have a project with plugin architecture (OSGi and Spring are used), we use pars extensively.
I can't find a proper description of what a par file is and why we use it?

What is a par file? Why do we need it in plugin development?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parchive ?

Answer (score 0):

[Eclipse Virgo](http://eclipse.org/virgo/documentation/virgo-documentation-2.1.1.RELEASE/docs/virgo-programmer-guide/html/ch04s02.html)

> An OSGi application is packaged as a JAR file, with extension .par. A PAR artifact offers several benefits:
>
> - A PAR file has an application name, version, symbolic name, and description.
> - The artifacts of a PAR file are scoped so that they cannot be shared accidentally by other applications. The scope forms a boundary for automatic propagation of load time weaving and bundle refresh.
> - The artifacts of a PAR have their exported packages imported by the synthetic context bundle which is used for thread context class loading. So, for example, hibernate will be able to load classes of any of the exported packages of the artifacts in a PAR file using Class.forName() (or equivalent).
> - The PAR file is visible to management interfaces.
> - The PAR file can be undeployed and redeployed as a unit.
>
> A PAR includes one or more application bundles and its manifest specifies the following manifest headers: